# Initialisation of pointer to structure using field elements

Tags: c, pointers, struct, initialization, literals

I was wondering if it is possible in C to initialise a structure in a following way:

```
struct Test* test = { .int_value = 10, .char_value = 'c', .pointer_to_float_value = (float*)1.512 };
```

If I try to do this with a structure defined in a way:

```
struct Test
{
    int int_value;
    char char_value;
    float* pointer_to_float_value;
};
```

I get an error for all elements of the structure:

```
error: field name not in record or union initializer
```

Is there a way to bypass this issue?

Comment: Doesn't seem to be working for me. The error 'error: cannot convert to a pointer type' appears when I run it with https://www.programiz.com/c-programming/online-compiler/

Comment: Overall you seem to be struggling with pointers. You cannot "store data in pointers", which is a recurring problem with this code. Pointers can only be used to point at data allocated elsewhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a number of problems with your code. You don't have a `=` sign and you are not handling pointers and types correctly.

It can be done like:

```
struct Test * test = &(struct Test){ .int_value = 10, 
                                     .char_value = 'c',
                                     .pointer_to_float_value = &(float){1.512f} };
```

Notice how it uses `(struct Test)` to set the type of the compound literal and `&` to get a pointer to it. The same applies to the float pointer.

Comment: I manually typed it in, so I forgot. Sorry.
Can you please explain to me why this syntax &(float){1.512f} is working? I do not really understand it. (meaning I do not understand why you use { } these brackets).

Comment: It gives you an unnamed float variable with the value 1.512 and then you take the address using & to get a pointer to the unnamed variable.

Comment: Understood. So { } are a part of this syntax? I did not see that before.

Comment: @Amaterastis The syntax is for "compound literals" that have been part of the standard since 1999 (C99). They behave like unnamed variables.

Answer (score 3):

It is indeed possible, but you are declaring a pointer to a struct and trying to initialize it as a struct (not pointer). The same issue with the pointer to float. The following should work:

```
    float a = 1.512;
    struct Test test_struct = { .int_value = 10, .char_value = 'c', .pointer_to_float_value = &a };
    struct Test *test = &test_struct;
```

Comment: I explicitly want struct Test* test definition. This is not the same.

Comment: @Amaterastis to have a pointer, you need a structure to point at, so it is a question of subsequently declaring a pointer to point at the struct. I will update the answer with this.

Comment: @Amaterastis This is the correct way of initializating a struct. It's entirely unclear why your code is using a pointer and what you hope to achieve with that.

Answer (score 3):

This syntax

```
struct Test* test { .int_value = 10, .char_value = 'c', .pointer_to_float_value = (float*)1.512 };
```

is invalid.

Instead you could use a compound literal as for example

```
float f = 1.512f;
struct Test* test = &( struct Test ){ .int_value = 10, .char_value = 'c', .pointer_to_float_value = &f };
```

From the C Standard (6.5.2.5 Compound literals)

> 5 The value of the compound literal is that of an unnamed object
> initialized by the initializer list. If the compound literal occurs
> outside the body of a function, the object has static storage
> duration; otherwise, it has automatic storage duration associated with
> the enclosing block.

Comment: The problem here is that the structure will be a temporary whose lifetime will be over just after the initialization, so the `test` pointer will point at unallocated memory.

Comment: @nielsen You are mistaken. There is no problem. The lifetime of the compound literal is the scope where it is defined,

Comment: This is actually working as intended. Is there a way to avoid having to define a variable 'f' for pointer_to_float? I would also like to avoid that.

Comment: @Amaterastis No, you may not take an address of an integer constant. You need to have an lvalue.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow You are right (as usually :-) ). Thank you for adding the C Standard reference. It is important to know the lifetime of the entity pointed at.

Comment: It will work, but there's no obvious reason why a pointer + compound literal should be used instead of a plain struct object. "Complicate things just for the heck of it" is a bad idea.

Comment: @Lundin The question is about the syntax of initialization of a pointer without creating explicitly an object of the structure type.

Comment: Yes. And how exactly does that make any sense? Access was too fast so we need to slow it down, or...?

Comment: @LundinFor example when you need to pass to a function a pointer to a structure in different parts of a scope.

Comment: @Amaterastis Yes, you can use another compound literal to initialize the `pointer_to_float_value` member:  `.pointer_to_float_value = &(float){ 1.512f }` or `.pointer_to_float_value = (float[]){ 1.512f }`. (The latter form initializes the pointer to point to the first element of a compound literal array of length 1 in this case, but it could be initialized to a longer length.)